# Windows 10 BCD missing

Tags: windows-10, boot, bcd

I've seen countless forum posts on how to rectify this problem, but I keep encountering random issues when doing so. I'm currently using a USB stick with the windows installation media to try to see what's going on. At this point I have no clue what's gone wrong. I can post any necessary screen shots if anyone can help me figure out what grave mistake I've made. Thank you.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ceSt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you only need to fix your bcd and mbr. This because your bcd and MBR table might be corrupted.

You can run command from USB Installation Media:
bootrec /fixmbr 
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /scanos
bootrec /rebuildbcd

Credit: https://geekzag.com/guides/computers/the-boot-configuration-data-for-your-pc-is-missing/